# Regular Expression for words with spaces

Tags: regular-expressions, matcher, pattern, space, words

I want to check for the following strings using regExpression:

1) Main-xxxxx-Accepted
2) Main-xxx xxx-Accepted

I used the below

```
String regEx = 'Main-[aA-zZ-]*-Accepted';

Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main-SUBMITTED-Accepted')); results in **TRUE**
```

It works fine for Main-SUBMITTED-Accepted.  But it fails for a word with spaces (non submitted)

```
Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main-NOT SUBMITTED-Accepted'));  results in **FALSE**
```

I tried these. Nothing works

```
String regEx = 'Main-[aA-zZ-\\s]*-Accepted';
String regEx = 'Main-[aA-zZ-\s]*-Accepted';
```

How do I check for words with spaces?

Comment: `[aA-zZ-\s]` means "any character that is either an `a`, or a character in the range `A` through `z` (which contains several non-letters, incidentally), or a character in the range `Z` through `\s` (which is an illegal range, apparently ignored by Salesforce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String regEx = 'Main-[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*-Accepted';
```

**Copy and Paste Code:**

> ```
> String regEx = 'Main-[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*-Accepted';
> System.debug(' @@@@@@ Main-NOT SUBMITTED-Accepted '+Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main-NOT SUBMITTED-Accepted'));
> System.debug(' @@@@@@ Main-NOT-SUBMITTED-Accepted '+Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main-NOT-SUBMITTED-Accepted'));
> System.debug(' @@@@@@ Main-NOT$-SUBMITTED-Accepted '+Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main-NOT$-SUBMITTED-Accepted'));
> System.debug(' @@@@@@ Main45NOT-SUBMITTED-Accepted '+Pattern.matches(regEx,'Main45NOT-SUBMITTED-Accepted'));
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly. But i wonder why _(underscore) in your answer instead of -(hyphen) mentioned in question!

Comment: It is hypen now.  Just a typo mistake @VigneshwaranG

Comment: Thanks that helped! perfect.  I removed 0-9 since I need to test for text only.  Thanks a lot.  Cheers!  [aA-zZ ]* with space doesn't work though.  It had to be [a-Az-Z ]*